# Resources in generic wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, resources

I am trying to use generic windows in WPF. I know how to create them, but I have hard time specify resources or anything else in the root element in such a window. Is this possible? You can use x:TypeArguments only in the root tag, so I am afraid that any definition outside of the root tag won't get recognized and handled without generic specification. I am missing something here?

This is a minimal (non)functional code:

MainWIndow.xaml

```
<local:ViewBase x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
            x:TypeArguments="local:TestViewModel"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<local:ViewBase.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TEST" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</local:ViewBase.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="TEST" Style="{StaticResource TEST}" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : ViewBase<TestViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
        : base(null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(TestViewModel vm)
        : base(vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

SomeClass.cs

```
public class ViewBase<T> : Window where T : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewBase(T vm)
    {
        DataContext = vm;
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase()
    {

    }
}

public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: is generic view really justified? View doesn't have to be generic only for the sake of DataContext - it is `object`, and usually you set it and forget.

Comment: This is only an example. I would not argue that it maybe doesn't make much sense only because DataContext, but I think that generic windows are somewhat usable (eg. 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/structured-navigation-overview'). I would like not to go to design decisions here. You can have generic windows. I just would like to know if there are some other restrictions during implementation of these as I couldn't find it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write `Window.Resources`:

```
<local:ViewBase ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TEST" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="TEST" Style="{StaticResource TEST}" />
    </Grid>
</local:ViewBase>
```

Comment: Yeah. I also think that this would be the best approach in this particular case. Although I would still like to know why the example in the question fails.